# Automating a button Press with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, request

I've been trying for a little while to figure out how to make an automated way to download the csv on this page:
https://razzball.com/mlbpitchingstats/

at the top, you can click a basic html input box and then click download on that box. I know I could figure out how to do this with a headless driver, but I have been trying to figure out how to do it with requests or somehow access the download button listener.

When monitoring the network tab, it seems there is no request to an api.
Is my only option to use a headless browser? is there anyway to grab this with requests? Any help would be huge!

Comment: I suspect it's just JS dumping the html table as a csv. Kind of annoying they did it that way, but whatever. You could use beautifulsoup to scrape the table and parse into csv yourself. Not sure if there are built in features to help with this, but doubt its the first time someone has tried to do that

Comment: of of looking, and i cant fully tell.. it seems that the data is populated by javascript.. so beautifulsoup would likely fail:(

Comment: The table data appears there though if you "view page source", so worth a shot with BS. But if not, you could use selenium to get that pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in your comment, the data is *not* populated via JS. Two clues about this:

1. if you look at the page source, the table is already populated in your browser html.
2. if you look at your browser network, there is no XHR request from your browser to acquire the data.

So as @SuperStew stated you could give it a try with Beautifulsoup, although it might be a little cumbersome, using a for loop over each `<tr/>` element.

If I needed to get that data in a usable format I would use pandas. Please see the documentation for the [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) method. This has the added bonus that it should help transform the data to the types you need, i.e., integers. But as the doc states, you should expect a little bit of data wrangling.

---

**edit**:

seems like  mlbstats blocks scraping through user agent filtering so you will have to use requests with spoofed user agent to get the page html:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "https://razzball.com/mlbpitchingstats/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = pd.read_html(response.content)  # will need wrangling
```